# angular not defined, cannot get angular side of app running

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I cannot get the angular side of my app up and running I am getting these 3 errors in the browser console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$minErr' of undefined angular-resource.js:8

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined angular-route.js:24

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

If I click my scripts in the browser dev tools they are all linking correctly and it is getting a code 200 in my server console, but it doesn't seem like the angular script is letting me create an angular object.

```
//Here is my angular app page code: 
angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
});

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
});

//Here is my layout.jade page: 
doctype
html 
    head
        //link(href="/favicon.icon", rel="shortcut icon", type="image/x-icon")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/vender/toastr/toastr.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css")
    body(ng-app='app')
        block main-content
        include scripts 

//Here is my included scripts.jade page:
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vender/jquery/jquery.js")
script(type="text/javasctipt", src="/vender/angular.min.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vender/angular-resource/angular-resource.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/vender/angular-route/angular-route.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="/app/app.js")
```

Here is a repository link if you want to see other parts of my code: 
https://github.com/dakhipp/meanTutorial

or let me know and I can paste what ever else you need to see. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, try this instead:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/main', controller: 'mainCtrl'});
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Angular";
}]);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to use ngResource for, but here is a working example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/DdtPhcLKDla6958YNuwc?p=preview

Comment: still getting the same 3 errors after that and my angular content is still not showing up

Comment: awesome, using your cdn angular links worked. it's weird tho because I even tried an older local version of angular and that didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: I did use bower to include angular and don't know much about bower, so maybe that has something to do with it. if you have any ideas about including my local angular file, I'll try them out if not thats cool too. thanks again

Comment: @agconti - When you say 'You keep redefining your app' - I thought that references like `angular.module('app')` were getter expressions, and that `angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])` (i.e. with the second parameter) was the setter expresion. Therefore, isn't there only one definition? Further, I understood that `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])` was bad practice as it causes pollution of the global space.

Comment: Ref https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module which says, under the heading Creation or Retrieval: _Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module._